# How to compare 'list of string' with 'enum string values' to return maximum match?

Tags: java, enums

The current code send `List<String>` but returns Enum if all values matches

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public enum Rara {
    MA_ON("ST"),
    MA_MAN("ST", "YS"),
    MA_IP("ST", "YS", "IC"),
    CODE("RC");

    Rara(String... codes) {
        this.codes = List.of(codes);
    }

    private List<String> codes;

    public static Optional<Rara> getValue(List<String> values){
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(rara -> rara.codes.containsAll(values))
                .findFirst();
    }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("ST", "YS")));  
          // Optional[MA_MAN]

    System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("ST")));  
          // Optional[MA_ON]
  }
}
```

But now requirements are if we get List as then max match enum should be returned

```
System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("ST", "YS", "IC", "BLABLA")));  
 //Should return MA_IP
System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("ST", "Bla", "Blabla", "BLABLA")));  
//Should return MA_ON
```

Note: IN case of ST & RC or any conflicting We need to pick the first one. (Like ST, RC we can pick MA_ON)

can anyone suggest how to achieve in same enum in getValue? (In place of containsALL if i add contains then it doesn't work. Not sure if it requires some maxmatch etc)

Comment: What about argument like `Arrays.asList("ST", "RC")`? Is such case possible? If yes what should be result (`MA_ON`, `CODE` or something else)?

Comment: @Pshemo: Yes i asked this, then they said pick the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly all you need is to

- know how many common strings has `codes` and `values` (for each enum)
- filter out those with no common elements
- pick one with maximum amount of common elements (or in case of many maxes first one from them)

To simplify our job we can create helper method to find only common elements in two lists. It can look like (I am assuming your Lists will have only unique elements)

```
private static List<String> commonElements(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(list1); // to avoid modifying `list1`
    common.retainAll(list2); // leaves in `common` only elements from `list2`
    return common;
}
```

With this we can

- map each enum to pair containing `enum, amountOfCommonElements` (we can use `Map.entry` to create pairs),
- filter pairs where `amountOfCommonElements` is 0,
- pick pair with max `amountOfCommonElements`
- get from that pair only `enum`.

Demo:

```
enum Rara {
    MA_ON("ST"),
    MA_MAN("ST", "YS"),
    MA_IP("ST", "YS", "IC"),
    CODE("RC");

    Rara(String... codes) {
        this.codes = List.of(codes);
    }

    private List<String> codes;

    private static List<String> commonElements(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(list1); // to avoid modifying `list1`
        common.retainAll(list2); // leaves in `common` only elements from `list2`
        return common;
    }

    public static Optional<Rara> getValue(List<String> values){
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .map(en -> Map.entry(en, commonElements(en.codes, values).size()))
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue()>0)
                .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
    }

}

 class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("ST", "YS")));
        // Optional[MA_MAN]

        System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("ST")));
        // Optional[MA_ON]

        System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("ST", "RC")));
        // Optional[MA_ON]

        System.out.println(Rara.getValue(Arrays.asList("STB", "RCC")));
        //Optional.empty
    }
}
```

Comment: It says :
Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)

Comment: What is your Java version? Tested in on Java 14 an 16 (don't have other installed).

Comment: Java 12 seems to be working too https://ideone.com/SE80zq

Comment: Actually Java 11

Comment: Usually general solution for inability to infer types in in lambdas is to provide them explicitly. For instance in case of `Stream<Rara>` we can use `.map( (Rara en) -> ...)` instead of `map(en -> ...)`.

Comment: Sorry It is Java 8 actually.

Comment: Then aside form what I said earlier you also can't use `Map.entry` since it was added in Java 9. Instead you could create instance of `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<K,V>`.

Comment: Working fine with Java 11